# Ubuntu crashing and restarting forever

Tags: crash

My system starts up and appears usable for maybe a minute or less before crashing and restarting. I was able to go to the text-instead-of-windows view and saw the following before it happened again:

[image]

To make it a little weirder, this is a NUC (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Unit_of_Computing), so apparently I have UEFI instead of/with GRUB.

Comment: It boots to ubuntu and for a minute you can use ubuntu like you normally do then it crashes or it boots directly to this screen and take 1 minute to do so?

Comment: It boots to Ubuntu for a minute and I can use it like I do normally.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a CPU or RAM failure.  In the GRUB menu you should be able to find `Memtest86` that you can run and test the RAM.  You can also try booting to a LiveCD and try it out and see if it still crashes.  If it doesn't crash, it is your installation that is probably corrupted.  If it does crash, then more than likely CPU, motherboard or RAM is defective.

Since your error codes are showing mce errors, I would push more towards defective hardware.

Memtest86 booting can be found at:

http://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm#boot

More information for MCE can be found at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I don't see Memtest86+ in the menu. I just updated the original post with a little more info about the hardware.